# How to access all the albums and then by clicking the album all the photos should open

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to show the image selecting option like whatsapp , first fetch list of all the album and then by clicking on that album all the photo should come and being able to keep track of all photo selected by user . i.e Multiple photo selection.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPuZe.jpg)

I have attached the image to show the requirement.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to use asset library for it,

Here are some libraries you could use:

[1. LimPicker (Similar to WhatsApp's image picker)](https://github.com/limhowe/LimPicker)

[2. Fusuma(Instagram like image selector)](https://github.com/ytakzk/Fusuma)

[3. YangMingShan(Yahoo like image selector)](https://github.com/YahooArchive/YangMingShan)